# .htaccess redirect to 403 error

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess

I have a website which watermarks photos (you may already know from previous q&a's). The orignal photos I use are secured using .htaccess using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !error.gif$
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ /error.gif [L]
```

When the user attempts to access the file it comes up with ERROR 404 which is fine but is there any way to get it to redirect to ERROR 403? (error.gif exists and is a 1x1 white pixel.)

I know .htaccess uses this to access 403 errors:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error-docs/403.shtml
```

I have created this file in the area, and have added the above line(s) together but it still redirects to ERROR 404?

I'm not very well educated with htaccess, so any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Full Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !error.gif$
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ /error.gif [L]
ErrorDocument 403 /error-docs/403.shtml
```

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a 403, include an `F` in the brackets where the `L` is:

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [L,F]
```

You can replace the `/error.gif` with a `-` which stops url rewriting since you have a separate document that gets served for the 403 so the error.gif doesn't do anything. That also means you can get rid of the RewriteCond, too.

Comment: Ok thanks. But when i put the url of a photo it still goes and show the photo. Any way to find out why?

Comment: never mind found the error most of my jpeg file have the extension `.JPG` instead of `.jpg` so changed your above line to `RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|JPG)$ - [L,F]` and it works. Thanks

Comment: you can also add a `NC` inside the brackets to make the match ignore case.